# why I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Tags: .net

I have a an array, that has data, howeever when I want to filter that array using linq Where, I am getting exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

so What I have

```
var images = await _repository.DeleteMerchantProductAsync(baseProductId, userId);
```

now I f I do images.count I get 1

However when I do images[0] it return null.

```
if (!images.Any())
{
    return false;
}
var paths = images
    .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.FileName))
    .Select(i => i.FileName)
    .ToList();
```

it throws exception at

```
var paths = images
    .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.FileName))
    .Select(i => i.FileName)
    .ToList();
```

Any reason ?

Comment: If `images[0]` is null then `i.FileName` will throw an NRE.

Comment: Simply pre-filter: `var validImages = images.Where(i => i != null);`. Then only use `validImages` starting at `if(!validImages.Any()) return false;`.

Comment: @LEE  you are right.